# jQuery click issues while performing instant search

Tags: jquery, html

I have an empty div class called `result`.

As I go along and type the search queries, the `result` div gets filled up with `item`  ( uses jQuery ajax).

When I do,

```
$(".result").click(function(){
    alrert("click on whole result class captured")
});
```

I get the alert message. But when I do,

```
$(".item").click(function(){
    alert("click on single item captured")
});
```

I don't get alert messages. 
Why does this happen? 
Is it because the item `divs` were inserted after the document was loaded?

Comment: Reading the code it seems like the opposite would happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer using `.on`

```
$(document).on("click", ".item", function(){
    alert("click on single item captured");
});
```

Because your items are added dynamically.

`click` or `bind("click")` can't be used for dynamically adding elements to DOM, because you will not attach your events "bindings".

`on("click")` (`live("click")` deprecated) keeps attaching events "bindings" through DOM changes.

Comment: Please don't post code using `.live()`. It's deprecated in favour of `.on()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on`

```
$(document).on("click", ".item", function() {
    alert("click on single item captured")
});
```

More details here http://api.jquery.com/on/